# including the same file but from different directories

Tags: php

I have a problem; actually I couldn't find any solution to it.

I have a file called cron_hourly.php

This file does some tasks and is supposed to run by a cronjob; I own like 4 sites with 4 different databases that have the same schema and structure; (The 4 sites are almost the same); the 4 databases just differ in the data they hold;

I need to run this file for the 4 databases; it makes some queries to the database and then email some information. Due to some hosting restrictions; I can use only 1 cronjob; so I have 4 cron_hourly in 4 different directories that does the same task but on a different db! So they have the some functions and variables; actually they are the same except that they connect to different databases!
The problem is; when I try to use the code below

```
     include 'path1/cron_hourly.php';
     include 'path2/cron_hourly.php';
     include 'path3/cron_hourly.php';
     include 'path4/cron_hourly.php';
```

I get the error 'Cannot redeclare someFunction() (previously declared in '
Actually this makes sense as the function was already declared in the same file from the other directory.

on the contrary; if I use include_once
Only the first file to be included runs and the others don't!
Is there any I can get around this? I want to run the four files without getting this error!
By the way; if(function_exists()) won't help! because as I said before I need to re-declare the functions over and over again for each file..

Comment: Can you use [`run-parts`](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/Linux/run-parts.8.html) in your cron job? Using this, you can run each script in turn from the one cron entry. I use this for my DB backup scripts

Comment: Why do you need to give the same names to the functions in your 4 included files?

Comment: Can you use `curl` to access each file as its own page?

Comment: @Phil Thanks for your suggestion; but I'd prefer I pure php solution. Thanks for taking the time to post this anyways; really appreciated :)

Comment: @Jocelyn Unfortunately I didn't write this code up; I'm assigned this task only; and in the same time; I'm not permitted to make any changes to the other files; so I guess that's why its a very difficult situation!

Comment: @jprofitt Smart suggestion! I'll consider this if I couldn't find any other solutions

Comment: @AdelAli You know `cron` isn't PHP so you are already using a non *pure PHP solution*. `run-parts` is very often used in cron scripts. See http://superuser.com/questions/402781/what-is-run-parts-in-etc-crontab-and-how-do-i-use-it

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use namespacing, see more here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

Comment: Namespaces aren't really going to help in this situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, even when you include a file within a namespace; the functions get declared in the global scope which results in the same error.